# Count number of times a string in mixed array php

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want an easy way to count a number of times the string "Apple" has present in the given

```
# My Array  :

$arr = array(
             1 => "Apple",
             2 => "Orange",
             3 => array(1=>"Bananna",2=>"Apple"),
             4 => "Grape",
             5 => "Apple",
             6 => array(1=>"Grape"),
             7 => "Orange");

# Want to count only "Apple"

$needle         = "Apple";

# My Function :

 function arrsearch($needle,$haystack,$return) {
    if(!is_array($haystack)) {
      return false;
    } 
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
              $return     = arrsearch($needle,$val,$return);
        }else if(strtolower($val) == strtolower($needle)) {
          $return[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $return;
 }

 $var = arrsearch("Apple",$arr,array());
 echo " Output : ".count($var);

 # Output : 3
```

I used the above function to find the number of times the string "Apple" in the array. Suggest me the best one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
function search_for($arr, $term)
{
    $count = 0;

    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item, $idx, $term) use (&$count) {
      if (false !== stripos($item, $term)) {
          ++$count;
      }
    }, $term);

    return $count;
}

search_for($arr, 'Apple'); // returns 3
```

The expression `function($item, $idx, $term) use (&$count) { .. }` is an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) declaration; it works just like a regular function, but you can inherit variables from the parent scope by using `use ($var)` or `use (&$var)` if you need to modify it too. More examples can be found on the manual page.

**Update**

For versions of PHP < 5.3, you'd have to encapsulate the counter using objects:

```
class RecursiveArraySearcher
{
    private $c = 0;

    public static function find($arr, $term)
    {
        $obj = new self;

        array_walk_recursive($arr, array($obj, 'ismatch'), $term);

        return $obj->c;
    }

    public function ismatch($item, $key, $term)
    {
        if (false !== stripos($item, $term)) {
            ++$this->c;
        }
    }
}

echo RecursiveArraySearcher::find($arr, 'Apple'); // 3
```

Comment: Wow, can you post a link explaining the `use` expression?

Comment: @JanTuroň Of course, I've updated my answer to explain the use of anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to flat the array and count the values:

```
<?php

function search_for($arr, $term) {
  $flatten_array = array();
  $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
  foreach($it as $v) {
    $flatten_array[] = $v;
  }

  $count_values = array_count_values($flatten_array);
  return $count_values[$term];
}

echo search_for($arr, 'Apple'); // print 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function like this ..

```
function finditem($item,$array){
    $count = 0;
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value) == true){
            $countx = finditem($item,$value);
            $count = $count + $countx;
        }else if($value == $item)
            $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}

echo finditem("Apple",$arr);
```

Hope it helps.